# Where do I give ideas?

Tags: development

I just had an idea. Someone must have probably thought of this and I'm not sure where to write this but here it is. 
We drag a file onto another file and a new folder is created with both files inside it just like in mobile operating systems.
Could anyone direct me to where I can give this idea.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! this is Q&A website about Ubuntu, your issue or idea belongs to meta or forums / blogs etc. where it can be discussed.

Comment: Most logical action: file a bug report against the package it concerns (nautilus). (a feature request is a bug ;) )

Comment: https://launchpad.net/nautilus

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I send feature requests?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a neat idea but this certainly isn't the platform to share it.

You might be able start a discussion thread on the Ubuntu Forums in the 'Other Discussions and Support' or other relevant section. [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=16)

If you have some technical skills, you could probably even mockup a wireframe/illustration of how this feature might look like or try and make a gnome extention that would allow you to add this feature to any file manager. It's an idea certainly worth investigating and you could do some basic dirty coding to make a simple prototype for the same even if I you can't build the actual feature completely. Put it out in the forums and see what other folks have to say about it :)