# Missing Armenian language pack in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: language-support

Dear Ubuntu support team
While working with Ubuntu 18.04 i noticed that the 18.04 version doesn't have the Armenian language in the options 
We would like you to add Armenian language in the next update
And also what would you suggest us to do while waiting for your update??

Comment: This isn't really a question; it's a request to add a feature.  This process was indicated in the accepted answer to the question:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests

Comment: @CentaurusA: I'd say that it's not an ordinary feature request either. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that too few strings are currently translated into Armenian.

Translation of Linux, including Ubuntu, is mostly done by volunteers. You may want to take contact with the [Ubuntu Armenian Translators team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-hy) and maybe get involved yourself.

It's not possible to just request a new language to be added. Establishing a new language and make it sufficiently translated is a big undertaking.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 have Armenian language pack, maybe we can use it for 18.04 version?

Comment: @HaykoKarapetyan: I suppose you mean 14.04. No sorry, that's not how it works. Maybe it would help if you edited your question and explained what exactly it is you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 14.04 version. How we can translate 18.04 and were i can find link for that?

Comment: @HaykoKarapetyan: My answer above includes a link to the Armenian translators team, and I'd advise you to get in touch with them. Hopefully they are able to guide you further. Otherwise, and if you want to help with Armenian translations of Ubuntu, post a message to the [ubuntu-translators mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-translators) (subscribe first).