# Adding a language missing from the supported languages list

Tags: 18.04, language-support

Is there any way (workaround) to add a language in Ubuntu 18.04, which is missing from the Install/Remove Languages list? I'm particularly interested in Armenian language.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Armenian language is absent in that list due to too few translations. Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084651).

There are Armenian keyboard layouts for typing, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly what I need, an Armenian Keyboard layout. But I don't seem to be able to find that too.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. I found out how to add the layout. Thanks

Comment: @AnahitHayrapetyan: Great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Armenian is already supported.

[image]

Comment: That's not Ubuntu, is it?

Comment: Yes. Why would it not be?

Comment: @user10853 thanks for the reply. However I'm still not able to find the language. I'm trying to add it from Language Support -> Install/Remove Languages. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1, just installed it half an hour ago. Am I looking in a wrong place? Or should I install some updates to get the language?

Comment: @user10853: Because I thought that that way to install languages wasn't available in Ubuntu.