# How to have touchpad settings in (K)ubuntu as advanced as in OpenSUSE?

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, settings

For the sake of more seamless detection of newer hardware (because of the kernel with which Kubuntu 19.10 comes by default) that I got in my recent laptop, I recently installed Kubuntu 19.10, and I'm quite satisfied with the OS, but... I noticed that the touchpad settings are significantly less advanced and customizable in the latest Kubuntu (19.10) than in OpenSUSE Leap 15.1 (or OpenSUSE Tumbleweed).

OpenSUSE touchpad settings:
[image]

Kubuntu touchpad settings:
[image]

In both cases I'm using libinput. Some principal differences are that in OpenSUSE there is more control, such as palm detection, acceleration, smoothly decelerated scrolling on release, time intervals, and so on, which is not present in Kubuntu. So I'm wondering what does one need to install to get the same kind of touchpad settings on Kubuntu?

Comment: You file it as a bug but as `[Wishlist]` for feature requests.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests

Comment: Please check `plasmashell -version` of both distros. What are they?

Comment: If you find that your Kubuntu version is lower than the other distro's, consider adding the ppa from https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=disco.

Comment: I'm seeing the same options in Kubuntu 19.10 with the backports ppa (plasmashell 5.17.2) you show for OpenSUSE. The same options are also present in Kubuntu 18.04 (plasmashell 5.12.9). So I'm wondering if it has anything to do with Kubuntu not handling your specific brand of touchpad (Elan).

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Version 5.12.8 on OpenSUSE Leap 15.1.  And it is version 5.16.5 on Kubuntu, so it is newer on Kubuntu. Yet the touchpad control is much more advanced on OpenSUSE. I'll try to upgrade the PPA to 5.17.2 on Kubuntu and see what this does.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Looks like that didn't help. The Touchpad settings snippet is still the same. Not sure why it's not like that on OpenSUSE.

Comment: Try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/). Someone maybe able to help!