# Ubuntu 20.04 Calculator customization

Tags: 20.04, calculator

Is there any way so we can customize (adding direct buttons i.e calculating any function) in Ubuntu 20.04 calculator?

Comment: You can do it by downloading the source of the calculator then changing the buttons the way you want them to be done.  `apt source gnome-calculator`  Also, you would need to make sure that you enable `source` in your Software & Updates.  After changing the source you would have to build it and install it.  I don't know how to change what it is that you are looking for, but I have changed other apps in the past by doing it this way.  I wouldn't be much help after you got the source downloaded.

Comment: You can also look into filing a Feature Request for the `gnome-calculator` to see if they would make it so that you could customize the buttons.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests