# Find all modified configuration files before upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, configuration

Especially during a `do_release_upgrade`, I am used to encounter a large number of prompts

> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation

which I usually answer with `N` to keep my modifications, but typically do so only after a thorough look at the differences with `D`. For of course I'd prefer to accept the maintainers version if my changes were irrelevant (and so I hope this file will at least not be questioned in the *next* upgrade), and I also wish to avoid the danger that my modified but old configuration might keep some legacy security risks alive. So in addition, I note down the names of all files complained about for later thorough inspection once the overall upgrade has completed and I have a lot of spare time available.

**Q1:** Can I obtain a list of all files that the system might consider "Modified (by you or by a script) since installation" before actually doing an upgrade? -- The answer to this is perhaps simply `sudo debsums --config --changed` (and right now gives me a list of almost 50 files)

**Q2:** If so, can I compare with / reset to the original version? This might be particularly helpful in the many cases where a local change I stupidly made to `/etc/foobar` can be relocated into an automatically included file `/etc/foobar.d/99-local`.

At any rate, investigating such differences before an actual upgrade may well facilitate and accelerate the upgrade process itself.

**Q3:** My gut feeling is that *sometimes* even an unmodified file is considered modified?! At least, the `D` option sometimes shows me differences only in terms of verbose comments (by the original author/maintainer)

Comment: This sounds like a feature request. Maybe this question could be of some help to you https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests

Comment: For Q2 see things like etckeeper. I'd ask about restoring the unmodified/original versions via debsums on unix/linux stackexchange separately. I think that's all that would be needed here, especially if debsums (or `sudo dpkg --verify`) could compare to specifyable versions of your distro.