# How can I change the frequency of the Lubuntu Update Notifier (Lubuntu 20.04)?

Tags: lubuntu, notification, schedule

It pops up every hour, even though I went into `Preferences > Software Sources > Updates` and set the schedule to `weekly` and rebooted (and `daily` is the shortest period offered in that dialog.)

There is no surprise *why* it is doing this: it is a result of the `/usr/lib/ubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-upg-notifier.sh` script having a hard-coded `sleep 3600` in its loop - but is there a better way of changing it than editing this file? In particular, is there a way to have it follow the schedule set in the `Software Sources Updates` tab?

**Update:** I did not want to be that entitled, self-absorbed guy who wants open-source projects to address his particular needs, but I see that I have become him. I realize now that I should just use the notifier for critical updates, and if I want anything more, I will write it myself (and share it, if I think it is any good.)

Comment: Have you tried installing the updates you have so that the notifier will stop bugging you for now?  It only runs when the system detects that you have updates ready to be installed.

Comment: @Terrance I tried that for a while, but it is just not feasible. I cannot just stop what I am doing every time an update comes in to deal with it, and then I am back to being bugged every hour - it is not as though I forget that I have seen the notification after an hour or two. Furthermore, I would like its behavior to actually conform to my preference settings, is that unreasonable?... If this is working-as-designed, then it is broken-as-designed from my point of view, and I will probably have to get rid of it, or at least go to critical security notifications only.

Comment: Maybe set your Automatically Check for Updates to Never then so that you can do it at your leisure.

Comment: @Terrance Well, as I mentioned above, if no-one comes up with an answer to the question *as posed*, then I will do something like that, but I say again, what's unreasonable with preferring it to conform to the preferences that it allows me to set?

Comment: No, it's no unreasonable.  But what you are asking would be a feature request to have the Software and Updates made to control the Updates Notifier.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests

Comment: @Terrance OK, thanks - I was hoping there was a workaround I could apply on my machine, and maybe there is, if I can find out where the preferences are stored, and run a slightly-modified copy of the script from my login profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lubuntu Update Notifier

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-update-notifier
- https://github.com/lubuntu-team/lubuntu-update-notifier (*upstream*)
- https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.4/Update-Notifier.html (*manual*)

The timer is version 0.1 used in *focal*/20.04 was 1 hour.

It was changed (24 hours) in version 0.2 found in *groovy*/20.10

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-update-notifier/+changelog

using exactly what you describe, as can be seen in

- https://launchpadlibrarian.net/480827201/lubuntu-update-notifier_0.1_0.2.diff.gz

FYI: The current version is 0.3 (used in *hirsute*), you could file a bug report (*request an easier, or more friendly way to change value*) if you wish another way, but I suspect you've already found the way.

Better choices no doubt exist, but volunteer *developer* time is limited.  The alternative would also be to suggest/code a fix yourself via the provided github link. You sound more than capable :)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/upg-notifier-autostart.desktop` worked for me.

If someone wants ansible role for some reason, feel free to copy https://github.com/matkoniecz/recovery-with-ansible/blob/master/roles/stop_upgrade_notifier_popup/tasks/main.yml