# Static IP address option on first time run of Ubuntu - Who do I ask?

Tags: system-installation, ip-address

I've installed many versions on Linux and the latest is Ubuntu on a Raspberry PI.

Is there any way that static IP settings can be an option when you install the OS for the first time?

Not having this option means that I have to configure the settings  once the system is up and running and I have yet to find a GUI that actually works.

I invariably have to go and edit a configuration file to get it to work. Not having and internet connection with a new install means I have no way of knowing which file to edit. It seems that every flavour of Linux has it own configuration file.

Can propose that this option is installed ?

Comment: Are you asking a question or asking for a new feature?

Comment: Yes it's possible and `ansible` comes to mind but you've provided no specifics as to what system (ie. a Core or *snap* based release, *deb* based system) so specifics will require an OS & release.  Please note this is **not** a Linux support site, but a Ubuntu (and *flavor*) site.

Comment: This is a user support site specific to Ubuntu and *flavors* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic .  It's not a bug tracker though where requests for features (as well as bugs discovered) belong, please refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs as being a *user-support* site, it only gets to *developers* if a user reports the requests on a tracker.

Answer (score 0):

This question has quite a few answeers to that already asked question. [Where can I send feature requests?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests)

Here is one of the answers.

14

You can make a feature suggest by submitting it as a "bug" at bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu.

Mark the bug with the tag [Wishlist] and the developers will know there is a demand. Only the maintainer of a project or bug superviser can then change the "Importance" to "Wishlist"

These types of bugs unfortunately are not usually given a high priority so you may have more luck trying to approach the upstream developers.

The link to actually file a bug "Report a bug" in the top right corner leads to a page, where the possibility to file a bug is hard to find. The link can be found in the section:

3. Tips and tricks >> 2. Filing bugs at Launchpad.net

It is also possible to file a bug now at the console if you type

ubuntu-bug
into the console and follow the instructions.

Note: I think this whole process could be optimized and I think it is strange to call feature requests still "bugs".

So I filed a feature-request here