# Copying files to a USB flash drive sometimes does not complete

Tags: usb-drive, filemanager, copy, transfer, memory-card

Sometimes when I copy a file from my laptop to a USB flash drive, the progress goes to just near 100% but remains at that stage and does not end.

I have this problem in Ubuntu 21.10 and in previous versions of Ubuntu too.

I am sure this is not USB memory problem because it does not have any problem in Windows. Also, even when I use a newly formatted USB drive, this problem happens too.

Does anyone know why this happens and is there a solution?

Here is a screenshot. It has been stuck like this for more than 10 minutes.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot that you posted shows that the file copy has been completed. Notice that "copying" has changed to the past tense "copied" and there is a check mark on the right.  Is this screenshot really the "problem" you are experiencing? Because it's not incomplete, as you claim.

Comment: Also make sure you *eject* the driver properly and wait for the message that it is safe to remove.

Comment: @Nmath please attention that when the copying is complete and done, there shouldn't be any black dot in notification. also when the copy is complete the notification should be erased. So please check it yourself before answer!

Comment: If you have a usability suggestion for the developers of Gnome, [you can use their GitLab site](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/-/issues). None of the volunteers on this site have creative control over the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04.

**The behavior you are experiencing is exactly as it was programmed to behave.**

The "black dot" in your screenshot is a circular progress indicator that gradually fills to black as the file operation completes.

When you click the circular progress indicator, a detailed progress window appears underneath with a linear progress indicator and additional information and a description about the status of the file operation.

Once you open the detailed progress information, this notification is not dismissed until you click away from it, even after the operation has completed.

You can tell that the file operation is completed because the language uses the past tense "Copied" and there is a check mark.

If you want the notification to go away, you need to click outside of it.

Comment: you did not get the meaning. in my screenshot, there was 3 simultaneously copying process. so you can only see just one because when the other 2 copying processes get completion, they disappeared. but the last one does not disappeared.

Comment: If you don't like how the app works, you can file a [feature request](https://askubuntu.com/q/28440).  Alternatively, you can use a different [flavour](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).