# Bring back the Xorg/Wayland toggle on login

Tags: xorg, 21.10, wayland

Because of screensharing, I need to switch back and forth between Xorg and Wayland often. I used to be able to log out, click the little cog, and choose `Ubuntu` for Wayland or `Ubuntu on Xorg` for Xorg. However, on Ubuntu 21.10 this is option is no longer there.

Can I bring it back?

Note: I know of the workaround via the gdm3 config file, but that's a hassle.

Comment: If you are asking for a feature or change in a feature this is not the place to do that.

Comment: I am not asking for a feature. As with many things in Linux, it's probably hidden and I can bring it back with a config change.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests#:~:text=You%20can%20make%20a%20feature,.launchpad.net%2Fubuntu.

Comment: thanks, but I am _not_ asking for a feature. Just for a way to switch conveniently at login.

Comment: What workaround are you talking about? What makes that solution insufficient?

Comment: Do you have a Nvidia card? If so, what version driver? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, no it's an integrated Intel Graphics Xe card.

Comment: @Nmath: It's considerably easier to be able to choose at login whether I want X11 or Wayland than to first access a terminal, remember the right files to edit, edit them and restart.

Comment: Does that enable the functionality in the greeter? We don't know what workaround you're referring to.

Comment: it doesn't, but it is the current way to switch between X11 and Wayland. Much rather I'd bring back the greeter functionality and I wonder if there's a setting for that.

Comment: @bluppfisk Are you talking about editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf? At the GRUB menu, if you choose the oldest kernel, is the login screen icon returned?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about 21.10 but here's the guide to bring back the toggle at login for 22.04 https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop