# Is there a way to add a "delete software" button upon right-click in the gnome app launcher?

Tags: gnome, launcher, gnome-shell-extension, software-uninstall

The question is really in the title, but more specifically.. does anyone know of a extension (or any other way) that can add a possibility to delete a software within the app launcher?
As shown on picture.

[image]

Although the software center is ok to install software, it feels unnecessarily clunky to have to delete software through it.

Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance?

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You might want to file a feature request for this.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests

Answer (score 0):

Installing and deleting software is not related to the daily use of the computer. It is related to the administration of the system. It also is not something you do several times every day. The Gnome Developpers therefore opted it wise to keep these aspects out of the interface in which you do your daily work. An added benefit is that inexperienced users then will not inadvertently delete software and require help desk assistance because of this.

This could be implemented by a Gnome Shell extension. Possibly, nobody took interest for the reasons mentioned above. You could file an enhancement request to the developers of Gnome Shell, but I feel that the chances that that would be accepted, are very small, for the reasons stated above.

Your options to remove software are 1) using the software center 2) using synaptic package manager or 3) use `apt remove` on the terminal.