# Catfish search output displays filenames in symlinked folders as though they are duplicate files

Tags: symbolic-link, dolphin

I'm using Dolphin and Catfish in Ubuntu Studio. I'm looking for a way to get Catfish to either exclude files in symlink folders from search results, or to display them so it is obvious that they are from a shortcut rather than a duplicate (e.g. in italics, as Dolphin does.) I can't find this in Preferences. Does anyone know if it can be done?

So for instance, in my "Morning routine" folder, and in my "Evening routine" folder, and in several others, I have a symlink to my folder of yoga videos which is nicely organized into my Multimedia folder with all my other long videos. I can see it's a symlink because it's written in italics in Dolphin.

But when I do a search using Catfish, every single yoga video I have appears repeatedly as a separate entity. I don't want this because a) it looks like I have many duplicated large video files and trying to find and eliminate duplicates means peering at each one, and I really do have some duplicates that I would like to eliminate, and b) if I am trying to locate the "mother" folder, like the true path to where the file belongs as I sorted it into my collection, this doesn't work. I copy the location from one of the symlinks rather than the original and paste it into Dolphin (rightclicking "show in File Manager always returns an error). The address pasted into Dolphin brings me into the yoga folder, but going up the tree just brings me up the path of wherever that symlink was placed, when I would like it to bring me up the tree of folders to my other exercise videos and other long videos.

Can Catfish be made to show shortcuts in italics or just not display them?

Thank you!

All packages are up to date.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I send feature requests?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests)

Comment: Possibly - I am thinking it might already be a feature but that I just don't know where the button is.