# What organization(s) manage the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file?

Tags: timezone

I've looked on several systems and seen these lines

```
111    # Allow client to pass locale environment variables
112    AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
I'd like to get this extended to include the "TZ" variable.
That way when I travel, and connect to some remote cluster, the dates on everything will be relative to my current timezone.

Comment: I've asked the managers of several of these clusters to add the TZ variable to the list.
Most of them refuse to do it, under the assumption that it will be a security breach.
I'm thinking that it would make more sense to get it into the Linux distros by default.
I don't know if this is an Ubuntu thing or an SSH thing though.

Comment: OpenSSH of course have their defaults, Debian can (and do, IIRC) further customize those defaults, and Ubuntu can also customize further the defaults they get from Debian.

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssd_config` is managed by the System Administrator. It's not that TZ is necessarily insecure, it's that the System Admin doesn't have the spare time to ensure (and put his reputation on the line) that exporting `TZ` **is** secure.

Comment: Based on my discussions with the various sysadmins, I don't believe they put the initial AcceptEnv entry in the file, so it had to have been added to the Ubuntu image or further upstream.

Comment: Is there a channel for me to propose this as an Ubuntu enhancement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I send feature requests?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests)

Comment: Also this seems to be a declined feature request over on Red Hat: https://superuser.com/a/1141861/334516

Comment: Thanks -- good lead on the SuperUser request.
I weighed-in my own comment on this, I think they're wrong.

Comment: Also, regarding the Feature Request, I'm not sure Ubuntu is the right place, or someplace further upstream.
I'm trying to find the "root" source of the OpenSSH source-code to see if that's where the sshd_config stems from.

Comment: I don't see a default AcceptEnv in this file

https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshd_config

so I'm guessing that the change goes in at the Debian/Fedora etc. level.

Comment: It is: https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/-/commit/aedb5d2ee2799e3a95b6913721533d2c42c496b3

Comment: Also imo you could just do something like `ssh -t server TZ=$TZ bash`