# Remove Ubuntu Pro From Update Screen

Tags: update-manager, ubuntu-pro

Recently after an update I'm seeing some additional greyed out items for Ubuntu Pro as well as an "Enable Ubuntu Pro" button on the software updater screen. I don't want to install Ubuntu Pro at this time and I also want to disable it from being shown on the software updater screen - see image below.

What are the steps to do that?

- Release Info: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Release: 22.04
- Codename:    jammy

*NB: This question has to do with the Software Update UI, not the command line interface.*

Edit:
tried this:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf.bak
```

then

```
sudo apt update
```

- This did remove the additional Pro packages from list on the command line, but had no effect on the Software Updater UI.
- So, still looking for good Software Updater UI solution.

[image: Updater Screen]

Comment: Did [looking for an answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434512/how-to-get-rid-of-ubuntu-pro-advertisement-when-updating-apt) not yield any restults?

Comment: What happens if you select the non-grayed out updates?  Does the Enable Ubuntu Pro button go to allow you to install those available updates?  This has been Canonical's choice to switch over the UA (User Advantage) that only supported 3 systems in the past to the Ubuntu Pro (which is commercially available) to private End Users for free to get the same support for 10 years as their commercial customers get for up to 5 systems.  If you don't want it, you are more than welcome to file it as a [Feature Request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests) to remove it.

Comment: I read some of those solutions, but I was looking for a simple setting that I could toggle on/off if I ever wanted to use the new version in the future. The thing is, I'm happy with 22.04 as it stands and I have no need for Ubuntu Pro. I noticed that in the Software & Updates GUI there is a new Ubuntu Pro tab, but the only button is "Enable Pro." What it should also have IMO is a check box to allow you to opt out completely.

Comment: Ken I don't think there is an easy way to disable those notifications right now. Please open a request in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+filebug with the suggestion to add the checkbox so the update-manager team can take a look into it. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inhibit ESM messages at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453749/inhibit-esm-messages-at-login)

Comment: @DanielT That's about a totally different message

Comment: @wjandrea Idk but I see https://askubuntu.com/q/1506011/1004020 and many other questions closed in favor of it. Specifically the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1454914/1004020 looks promising. But I guess https://askubuntu.com/q/1434512/1004020 may be a better dupe target

Comment: @DanielT None of those links address the issue in this question. This question is about the Ubuntu Pro messages showing up in the Software Updater UI. Please see the original question and screen shot.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1434512/1004020 as zwets linked first, had both of the below answers. However I retracted my confusing close vote because I should have selected it as the dupe target not the other one I actually selected

Answer (score 2):

There is a guy who patched the used package of `ubuntu-advantage-tools` with a fake version of it.
That resolved the same issue for me!

You can find a guide and the files at [this GitHub page](https://github.com/Skyedra/UnspamifyUbuntu)

Answer (score -1):

To Dis-able the **Update Ubuntu Pro** option from **Software Updater** window :
Use below mentioned command in terminal.

```
sudo pro config set apt_news=false
```

Comment: nice, simple and did *not* work for me (U22, XFCE). Still looking for a solution. It confuses my customers!

Comment: Yeah, I tried that command too, and I was able to install non-Pro packages for the first time again, but the Pro-dependent packages still came through and I got the "Enable Ubuntu Pro" or "Remind Me Later" hateful choice.  I'm beginning to wonder, what would it take to fork Ubuntu back to freedom, away from Canonical?

Comment: Sorry to say that this had no effect. On the UI, still seeing the Enable Pro button and the software list.